# MySQL update with group by and variable

Tags: mysql

I want to update a table but need to group by a shop name. I want all grouped entries with the same shop name to get updated with the same ID. All other shops should get an own ID.

So that's what I tried:

```
SET @row_number:=0;

UPDATE `TABLE 75` as t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT search_shop FROM `TABLE 75` WHERE sap_id = '' GROUP BY search_shop) as t2
ON t1.search_shop = t2.search_shop
SET sap_id = CONCAT('XX',@row_number:=@row_number+1)
```

With this query every entry get's an own ID - even the ones that have the same name.

So I want something like this:

```
shop_name - sap_id
sm_name_1 - XX1
sm_name_2 - XX2
sm_name_2 - XX2
sm_name_3 - XX3
```

And so on.

Thanks for the help in advance! :)

Comment: Just a note, instead of joining the table to itself you could simply write `where sap_id = ''`. Or is the query more complex than you show here? It can matter if you have to update a single table or you have to join it.

Comment: I needed to join it because I can't update a row with group by, can I? The main purpose of the join should be to get same named entries as a group and update them all with the same sap_id. But - as I mentioned in my question - with that query every row gets their own ID no matter if there are other same named entries.

Comment: Well, probably it would be a good idea to provide sample data and desired result. Your join and group by really makes no sense, no offense, or I didn't understand at all, what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think you're right. If this query made sense it would work as expected, but it doesn't. So this is what I'm trying to achieve: There is only one table. This table has a new column named sap_id. I want to fill this column with a new generated ID. But there are duplicates (shops with the same name in shop_name column). Shops with the same name should get the same ID (so that you can see that they belong together). That's it :) Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`shop_name` varchar(9), `sap_id` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`shop_name`, `sap_id`)
VALUES
    ('sm_name_1', ''),
    ('sm_name_2', 'XX2'),
    ('sm_name_2', ''),
    ('sm_name_3', 'XX3'),
    ('sm_name_3', ''),
    ('sm_name_4', ''),
    ('sm_name_5', '')
;

update t
inner join (
  select
  t.shop_name
  , CONCAT('XX', @rn := if(@prev = shop_name, @rn, @rn + 1)) as sap_id
  , @prev := shop_name
  from
  t
  , (select @prev := null, @rn := 0) var_init
  order by shop_name
)sq on t.shop_name = sq.shop_name
set t.sap_id = sq.sap_id;

select * from t;

| SHOP_NAME | SAP_ID |
|-----------|--------|
| sm_name_1 |    XX1 |
| sm_name_2 |    XX2 |
| sm_name_2 |    XX2 |
| sm_name_3 |    XX3 |
| sm_name_3 |    XX3 |
| sm_name_4 |    XX4 |
| sm_name_5 |    XX5 |
```

- see it live in an [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c6633/1/0)

Comment: Looks very good, nice idea with the order by :) Thank you very much!